# Using python Django and Mysql. Data won't inserted into MySQL due to Binlog

Tags: python, mysql, django, binlog

When I use django to design a website and delopy, I find I have some trouble if I use MySQL that the **Binlog** is activate( format:**STATEMENT**).

There are my settings for this deployment:

- Django based website
- uwsgi
- Ningx
- MySQL

The  first step, I need to migrate my models to databese, so I input like this:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And traceback like this:

```
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1665, 'Cannot execute statement: impossible 
    to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table 
    uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row- 
    logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.')
```

After searching in Internet, I know the one way to fix it is to change the Binlog format, which works perfectly for me.

But I still want to know how to fix it if I don't want to change my Binlog configuration. I think Django can support this format for Binlog.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and fixed it by changing the isolation level to "repeatable read". You really only need it to apply the migrations then you can probably(?) remove it. In settings.py I changed my DATABASES setting to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {                                                                                         
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                                                                                 
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': 'db_host',
        'PORT': 'db_port',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': db_conn_max_age,
        'OPTIONS': {                                                                           
            'isolation_level': "repeatable read",                                                        
        },                                                                                     
    }                                                                                            
}
```

then ran `python manage migrate`, then remove the `OPTIONS` entry. Pay attention to [these risks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/#default-mysql-isolation-level-is-read-committed).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to set **Binlog** format as **ROW**

for setting the format please use this,

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
```

After that use below query for confirming

```
mysql> show variables like 'binlog_format';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and I indeed know this is efficient way to fix this problem; but my administrator tells don't change the binlog format, so I wish have other solution.

Answer (score 0):

After my searching yesterday, I have get a summery solutions for this problem.

> - First solution: Change the Binlog format.
>     As Hariprakash said, we can change the Binlog format and fix this problem. In most of cases, it is the best way to fix it.
>     You can change the setting in two ways:
>
>   1. Hariprakash ways, but it only influences the settings in session. When you shut down the session, the seetings will be lost.
>   2. You can revise Mysql settings file `my.cnf`
>        In `my.cnf`, you need to add `log_bin=mysql-bin` and set the `bin_format=ROW` or `binformat=MIXED` which based on your choice. And then, you need to restart Mysql service. That will be effective forever.

---

> - Second solution: Change the default storage engine for Mysql
>     Before you revise default storage engine, you need to check how many kinds of your supporting engine.
>     `show engines;`
>     And you can change the default storage engine.
>
>   - In settings file `my.cnf`, you should insert `default-storage-engine=INNODB` after `[mysqld]`, and remember you **must** insert `server-id=1`, this number is used for recognize your host. **Do not** make other host have same number.
>   - Also you can use the Mysql version for 5.5.4 or older, which uses MyISAM as default storage engine according to [Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/).

---

Although there are two ways to fix the problem, but I think there are not the best solution. If someone have an better answer which do not revise `my.cnf`, please tell me.